# Pass form data via ajax to php and load in datatables

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

Been struggling to find a solution for days now, any advice will be helpful and jsfiddle will be amazing.

I am able to get the following to work without the datatable plugin using the regular Table
Don't worry about the security, I will apply that later.
I just desperately want the Datatable to show my returned data

**Here is the problem** :
- I have a form with 4 inputs, the user have to select at least one of them.
- On submit the data needs to be sent to PHP script which will search the database and return multiple lines of data
- I want to display that data using the Datatables plugin

Here is my HTML code :

```html
<section class="div-wrapper">
  <form role="form" class="form-inline" action="process.php" method="post" id="search_form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="search_brand" class="control-label lab-format search-labels">Product Brand</label>
        <select name="search_brand" id="search_brand" class="form-control input-sm">
          <option value="">-Select-</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="A">A</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="search_serial" class="control-label lab-format search-labels">Serial Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="search_serial" id="search_serial" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Serial Number">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="search_id" class="control-label lab-format search-labels">Inventory ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="search_id" id="search_id" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Inventory ID">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="search_imei" class="control-label lab-format search-labels">IMEI # 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="search_imei" id="search_imei" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="IMEI # 1">
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" id="search" class="submit-button pull-right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>

<div>
  <h4>Search Results</h4>
</div>
<section id="search_result_success" class="div-wrapper" style="">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="search-output-table table table-hover table-responsive cust-output" id="search_success_output_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="table-item">Item ID</th>
          <th id="table-brand">Brand</th>
          <th id="table-model">Model Code</th>
          <th id="table-imei1">IMEI</th>
          <th id="table-serial">In Value</th>
          <th id="table-cr-date">Location</th>
          <th id="table-status">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Here is my Jquery code :

```js
$("#search_form").submit(function(e) {
  isValid_src = true;

  if ($.trim($("#search_serial").val()) == '' &&
    $.trim($("#search_brand").val()) == '' &&
    $.trim($("#search_id").val()) == '' &&
    $.trim($("#search_imei").val()) == '') {
    isValid_src = false;
    $("#search_serial, #search_brand, #search_id, #search_imei").css({
      "border": "1px solid red",
      "background-color": "#ffcccc"
    });
  } else {
    $("#search_serial, #search_brand, #search_id, #search_imei").css({
      "border": "",
      "background-color": ""
    });
  }

  if (isValid_src == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    var str_inv_search = $("#search_form").serialize();
    $("#search_success_output_table").children("tbody").remove();
    $('#search_success_output_table').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "destroy": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "process_inv_search.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
          str_inv_search
        }
      },
      "columns": [{
        "data": "item_code"
      }, {
        "data": "brand"
      }, {
        "data": "model_code"
      }, {
        "data": "imei1"
      }, {
        "data": "in_value"
      }, {
        "data": "rack_location"
      }, {
        "data": "delete_flag"
      }],
      "order": [
        [6, "asc"]
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

My PHP code :

```
if(isAjax()){
  if($_POST['search_serial'] != NULL){
    $post_inv_sr = $_POST['search_serial'];
    $q = "sr_num = '{$post_inv_sr}' ";
  }elseif($_POST['search_id'] != NULL){
    $post_inv_id = $_POST['search_id'];
    $q = "item_code = '{$post_inv_id}' ";
  }elseif($_POST['search_imei'] != NULL){
    $post_imei = $_POST['search_imei'];
    $q = "imei1 = '{$post_imei}' ";
  }elseif($_POST['search_brand'] != NULL){
    $post_brand = $_POST['search_brand'];
    $q = "brand = '{$post_brand}' ";
  }

  $json = null;

  $search_query   = "SELECT item_code, brand, model_code, imei1, in_value, rack_location, delete_flag ";
  $search_query  .= "FROM inv1 WHERE ";
  $search_query  .= "$q";
  $search_query  .= "ORDER BY delete_flag ASC";

  $search_result = mysqli_query($connection, $search_query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_result)){
    $json[] = $row;
  }

  if($json == NULL){
    echo "N";
  }else {
   echo json_encode($json);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. This part:

```
    "data": {
      str_inv_search
    }
```

should be:

```
    "data": str_inv_search
```

You're nesting your serialized form data into `$_POST['str_inv_search']`, which isn't necessary.

Comment: Dear Barmar, thanks for checking my issue.
I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work :-(
Can you please check once again.
Thank you

Comment: Hi Sorry for late response. I was in transit.
var_dump($_POST); shows correct response in json format with data :
As i mentioned earlier all is working fine except the way to pass data to the php script